# $E(HT) = \sum_T \sum_H (HT\cdot f(H,T))$

Tags: probability, statistics

I was given this formula by my statistics instructor for a problem in which a fair coin is tossed twice and $H$ is denoted the number of heads. The coin is then tossed $2^H$ times and $T$ is denoted the number of tails. After calculating the joint probabilities, we used the formula

$$E(HT) = \sum_T \sum_H (HT\cdot f(H,T))$$

to get

$$(1\times1)\times(1/4) + (1\times2)\times(1/8) + (2\times1)\times(1/16) + (2\times2)\times(3/32) + (2\times3)\times(1/16) + (2\times4)\times(1/64) = 1.5.$$

This value was then subtracted by $E(H)*E(T)$ to get the value of $Cov(H, T)$. I haven't been able to find this formula for $E(XY)$ so can anyone point to a source with this formula or demonstrate how this formula is arrived? Thanks.

Comment: It's the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Answer (score 0):

[image: P(h,t) the join pmf of H and T]

the join pmf of H,t denotes as P(h,t) is shown above. Assume that you know how to find the join pmf, I don't explain here. actually, I don't understand your question. For which formula you are asking for help?
H could only take the value of 0,1,2
T could only take the value of 0 1 ...2ˆh(maximum is 4)
then E(HT)=1*1*P(1,1)+1*2*P(1,2)+2*1*P(2,1)+2*2*P(2,2)+2*3*P(2,3)+2*4*P(2,4)

ok I get it now. let X=HT, then P(X=ht)=P(H=h,T=t)=f(H,T). By simple substitution, you get this formular。PS: first time to answer question here, sorry for my terrible formatting.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Would you mind explaining how you arrived at your expression for the joint pmf? The way I calculated a specific joint probability was multiplying the probability for H = x with the probability for T = y. So for example, the probability H = 0 is 1/4 which corresponds to 2^0 = 1 flip. The probability that T = 0 is 1/2 so the probability of H = 0 and T = 0 is 1/8.

Comment: EDIT: It looks like you multiply the number of combinations for T, the number of combinations for H, and probability of success(?) (where success is defined as either heads or tails) raised to the number of tosses.

Comment: P(H,T)=P(T given H)*P(H) and P(T given H) and P(H) are binomial distributions with probability of success equal 0.5, and for H, the number of experiments is 2, for T given H, the number of experiments is 2 to the power of H.

Comment: This is simply the definition of conditional probability